# How to set input_tensor on a loaded model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I've created a model based on VGG16:

```
base_model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False,
                   input_tensor=next_batch["image"],
                   input_shape=INPUT_SHAPE)
x = base_model.output
# model customization follows, not relevant
```

Note that in the snippet I specify `input_tensor` which comes from `tf.data.Dataset`.

I've trained the model for some epochs and then saved it using `model.save("model.h5")`

Now, when I try to load the model using `load_model("model.h5")` and continue training it, I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must
>   feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_1' with dtype float and
>   shape [?,512,512,3]
>            [[{{node input_1}} = Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,512,512,3],
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]]

So the question is, how to specify `input_tensor` on a loaded model?

Answer (score 0):

After reading through the code responsible for model loading, I came up with the following solution:

```
class InputLayerFix:
    @staticmethod
    def from_config(config):
        return InputLayer(input_tensor=next_batch["image"],
                          dtype=config["dtype"],
                          name=config["name"],
                          batch_input_shape=config["batch_input_shape"])

custom_objects = {"InputLayer": InputLayerFix}
model.load_model("model.h5", custom_objects=custom_objects)
```

This code relies on the fact that the deserialization routine first checks `custom_objects` for classes to instantiate (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py#L155)